# How can I make Stata display all the value label in the Data Editor?

Tags: label, editor, stata

I am working with a dataset in which I have information on the occupation in which an individual is employed (see image below). In the data editor, I'd like to be able to read the occupation, while now Stata truncates the information displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
format occ2010 %20.0g
```

You can change `20`for any width you like.

Comment: If you are using Stata 16 or newer you can also drag the column widths where the variables are displayed at the top of the grid.